# Figuring a loan payoff amount

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, finance

I have a loan for a principal amount of \$117,000.00 at 9.75% interest and a total amount due (including the interest for 84 months) of \$191,805.60.  I had 84 months to pay it off, or I could pay it off early, without penalties.  I have made 61 payments totalling \$139,287.40.

How do I calculate the principal balance due, not including any *further* interest?

Comment: this question is not fit for asking here.

Comment: @TaoHong洪涛 Why not?  How would you solve such a problem?  I would use math.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is the 9.75% a monthly or annual interest? compound of course, right?

Comment: @TaoHong洪涛: why not? seems like a legitimate mathematical question to me. The [faq] explicitly says: *Mathematics - Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level [...]*

Comment: The interest is compound, but there is an early payoff clause, that I don't need to pay interest on the principal balance that is left and that I now want to pay off.

Comment: Just in case I did not answer your question, I borrowed $117,000.00 at 9.75% for 84 months, which comes to a total amount due,(if I take the full 84 months to pay it off) of $191,805.60.  However, I want to now pay off the balance (principal balance left, without interest).  Is that enough info?

Comment: @t.b. maybe should be asked here http://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is financial mathematics.  I am teaching a class where we do problems like this.

Comment: @Mindy: There are a few things one needs to know. The most important is whether the $9.75$ is the *nominal* yearly rate, or the *effective* annual rate. If nominal, then interest rate is likely $9.75/12$ monthly, compounded monthly, which means effective annual rate is higher than $9.75$.  One will also have to know whether the $61$ payments were all equal.

Comment: @Graphth then we're expecting you to post an answer :)

Comment: @J.D. I assume the answer to Andre's last question is the payments are all equal, but I don't know the answer to the first question.  Is it a nominal annual rate, or an annual effective rate?  I can't answer it without knowing that.

Comment: @Mindy Do you have any updated on the inconsistency I mentioned in my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

**Payments:** First off, I assume the payments are equal.  This is standard for loans, though I'm sure there are cases where it is different.  If 84 payments total \$191,805.60, then each payment must be \$2283.40.  I will also assume the first payment is 1 month after the loan is taken out, which is also pretty standard.

**Interest rate:** Next, we need to know about the interest rate.  Is it an annual effective rate of 9.75% or is it a nominal (meaning in name only) rate 9.75% compounded monthly?  The latter is a fancy way of saying the interest rate for each month is 9.75/12% = 0.8125% = 0.008125.  I can do the problem both ways.  The answers should be relatively close to each other.  If the interest rate is an annual effective rate, then let $j$ be the monthly rate.  We would have $(1 + j)^{12} = 1.0975$, or $j = \sqrt[12]{1.0975} - 1 \approx 0.0077830371$

**Answer:** 61 payments have been made, which means there are 23 left.  Let us assume the 61st payment was made today, so the 62nd is due in exactly one month.  Then, the outstanding loan balance is equal to the present value today of the remaining payments.

Assuming a nominal 9.75% interest rate, convertible monthly:
$$\begin{align*}
&2283.4 \cdot (1.008125^{-1} + 1.008125^{-2} + \cdots + 1.008125^{-23}) \\
&= 2283.4 \cdot \frac{1.008125^{-1} - 1.008125^{-24}}{1 - 1.008125^{-1}} \\
&= 2283.4 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.008125^{-23}}{0.00825} \\
&= 47658.00
\end{align*}$$

Assuming an annual effective rate of 9.75%, so the monthly rate is $j \approx 0.0077830371$:

$$2283.4 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.0077830371^{-23}}{0.0077830371} = 47915.88$$

Note, these are about \$257 apart, which isn't all that big relative to \$48,000.

**Inconsistency:** However, there is something wrong with this problem.  The amount of the loan should be equal to the present value of all of the future payments, at the time the loan is made.  Since the loan is for \$117,000, the present value of all the 84 payments,  at the exact time the loan is made, should also be \$117,000.  However, it turns out that it is actually:

$$2283.4 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.008125^{-84}}{0.00825} = 138620.63$$

or for the other interest rate:

$$2283.4 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.0077830371^{-84}}{0.0077830371} = 140413.40$$

Neither of these are anywhere near \$117,000, so something is going on here.  That is, we don't have all the information, or some of the information we have is wrong.  I used a financial calculator to solve for the monthly interest rate in the case of 84 equal monthly payments of \$2283.40, with the first a month from now, where the loan is for \$117,000, and the answer is 1.282503786%.  This is the monthly interest rate which translates to a yearly rate of
$$1.01282503786^{12} - 1 = 0.1652339966$$
In other words, it corresponds to a 16.5% annual effective interest rate.